# Show Windows file permissions when Security tab is disabled

Tags: windows-xp, file-permissions

In an environment where the **Security** tab in **Properties** is disabled and cannot be enabled, is there an alternative way to display the permissions on a folder?

What if the user has normal command line access without admin privileges?

Comment: Able to access command prompt?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Powershell and the Get-Acl command

```
PS D:\> Get-Acl

   Directory:

Path              Owner                            Access  
----              -----                            ------  
D:\               NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller      Everyone Allow  FullControl
```

Use it in conjunction with Get-ChildItem (aliased with dir and ls) to get the permissions for the files.

```
PS D:\> Get-ChildItem | Get-Acl
Or, using the alias:
PS D:\> Get-Acl | fl

PS D:\> Dir | Get-Acl
```